# How can I sum values from controls in MVC right after the user enter the value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this in my View:

```
<div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q7, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q7)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q7)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q8, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q8)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q8)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q9, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q9)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q9)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Q10, new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Q10)
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Q10)
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

The user will enter this values and I have to sum all the values and show the result in another control, how can I do this in my View? Do i have to use Javascript or can i do it in a different way?

Thanks

Comment: Right after, yes, you need to use javascript.

Comment: This is client side. look into using knockout and have a client side view model track that

Comment: Which inputs are you trying to sum and which input will have result value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke jquery's .focusout() for each editor, as all your editors will have their model property name id.

```
> $("#Q7").focusout(function() {
>         // access the values of each textbox through $( "#Qn" ).text()
          // cast, validate and add
>      })
```